# JavaScript date to timestamp calculation doesn't work for 8th and 9th of any month

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have the following JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/5Hapw/

When selecting a date, a variable will alert to say the timestamp - however, on the 8th and 9th of any month, the timestamp is always wrong.

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you want to do in onSelect event on result? Date object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't pass a second parameter to parseInt (the base) javascript will guess at it.  It's probably guessing wrong.  Pass 10 in as the second param to all your parseInt calls (you can get rid of the code that truncates the zero from the month - incidentally adding this code to truncate the zero from the day of month would also work)

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Hapw/4/

Comment: Interesting -- I never would have guessed that JavaScript assumes `parseInt("07")` is supposed to be an octal number -- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp

Comment: Correct. Only all I had to do was substr the 0 from the front of the day and month...

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is in parsing a string into a number. If you don't specify a radix, and the string starts with a zero, it will be parsed as an octal number:

```
parseInt("017") === 15

parseInt("08") === 0 // because 8 is not a valid digit in octal numbers
```

The solution is to specify the radix 10:

```
parseInt("08", 10) === 8
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/5Hapw/6/

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved in your case by casting it as a number -- replace `parseInt(selection[0])` with `Number(selection[0])`.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/5Hapw/5/

Answer (score 0):

Actually javascript interpret those variable in octal values please convert them into decimal by using. I believe you are taking a string and parsing it for a value. some thing like this. Then please do the following thing.

```
parseInt(month_val);
```

And here is my snippet f code which I'm using to check the valid date.

```
    var birthdate = element.value.split("-");
    var JDate = new Date(parseInt(birthdate[2],10), parseInt(birthdate[0],10) -1, parseInt(birthdate[1],10));
    valid = (parseInt(birthdate[0],10) - 1 == JDate.getMonth() && parseInt(birthdate[1],10) == JDate.getDate() && parseInt(birthdate[2],10) == JDate.getFullYear());
    return valid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont known why you try parse *date* parameter (by spliting)? Parameter *inst* contain next fields:

- inst.selectedDay
- inst.selectedMonth
- inst.selectedYear
- and more ...

  Date.UTC(inst.selectedYear,inst.selectedMonth,inst.selectedDay);